# Sync Sql server data to dropbox automatically

Tags: sql-server, dropbox, zapier

There is any aplication to export data from a database and them write it into a file, them sync with the dropbox and every hour i want  the database to be checked for updated data or new rows inserted, if true, the file should be updated and synced in dropbox.
Is this possible?

I found zapier, that does more less what i want, but only updates the file when there is a new row, doesnt check updated rows.

Comment: I recommend looking into Microsoft PowerApps.  This will allow you to do this with a no code solution, if you have access to those tools.

Comment: I have acesss to those apps, How can I use powerapps to solve my problem?